# Mount a workstation dir upon login to server over ssh

Tags: ssh, mount

I'd like to have a local directory be mounted upon logging into a remote server via SSH. So if I were to ssh into foo.bar.com as user baz then there would be a directory mounted in /home/baz/roaming - that corresponds to my local workstations roaming dir - for the length of my connection.

My local workstation in this case is a Mac, but the methodology is likely more generally *nix in nature. Most likely an SSH wrapper would be necessary that performs some sort of mount related actions after a new ssh connection occurs.

Has anyone done this? Suggestions or existing utilities would be very helpful!

Comment: If you can SSH back from whence you came, you could probably do some `.bashrc` magic to use `sshfs` to mount a location on the system you logged in from at `$HOME/mnt`.